# Zend Studio Debugger - StepThrough Possible?

Tags: php, debugging, zend-studio

Lately I've been using a lot of classes that implement ArrayAccess and Iterator in PHP. Its fantastic functionality, but a bit of a pain when I'm debugging. Specifically, since I'm manually defining these array access and iteration methods for my classes, when stepping through code in PHP its a bit of pain to be cycling through these interface methods over and over for routine things.

My question: is there a docblock comment or some other signifier that I can put on my methods so that the Zend Studio debugger will automatically Step Over? I realize that I can manually step over but it gets tiresome switching back and forth between Step Into and Step Over. Any solutions out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can put in your code to influence the Zend Debugger afaik.

For the various control options see

- http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/analyzing_debugger_results.htm

If you want to exclude files or resources from being stepped into, try a Step Filter

- http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/step_filtering_preferences.htm

Comment: Step Filter is in the right direction, but its unfortunate that you can't control the debugger through the use of doc blocks.

Comment: @Jarrod you could file a Feature Request for it with Zend though.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible without customize Zend Debugger. Therefore, I believe that exists other solutions for your problem. Try to create a block like a if, test an controller variable and brake inner.

```
if($test_an_controller_variable) { // Like a $i of an iteration, and you don't need wait ane iterations until that.
    $b; // set a breakpoint to here.
}
```